# How do I use the native hand cursor in my C# application?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I use a custom cursor set on my computer. However, on my `LinkLabel` object, the hand cursor looks different than the one I have. Now I **know** how to use a custom cursor on my application, **but** what I want to know is how to use the hand cursor **used** by the system. So if ever my app runs on a different computer where the user has their **own** custom cursor set, the app will use that.

I don't want a single custom cursor for the `Cursors.Hand`, I want it to use whatever is being used by the system. How do I do it? Sorry if my English is a bit hard to understand, it's not my native language.

Comment: Just about to answer this when I decided to search. Turns out [I already had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016995/un-antialiased-hand-cursor-in-windows-forms-apps).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find it when searching, probably used the wrong terms. I can't believe we're now in Windows 10 and Microsoft still hasn't fixed this stupid shortcoming.

Comment: It is not a Windows problem, it is a WinForms issue. New releases of Windows won't change anything. It'll have to be a new version of WinForms. Don't hold your breath. It was announced a few years ago that WinForms was in maintenance mode, with no new features to be added, only bug fixes. It was kind of a surprise that high DPI support was added in v4.5 (at least to me). More like a nice bonus. Don't count on them fixing something that isn't actually broken. Microsoft still can't decide what UI framework they want to settle on, it's changed more times than I can count.

Comment: Oh no, I'm not saying it's related to Windows 10, I'm more saying they're already shipping this new operating system after lots of years and yet that simple problem they haven't dealt with yet. Heck, even the Windows 10 Mail app has this problem where links in emails show that old cursor instead of the system's custom one.