# Improve LinkLabel - Use system hand Cursor and Change Link Color

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linklabel

`LinkLabel` control has some annoying problems:

- By default, it doesn't use any system colors (namely `Color.Blue` instead of `SystemColors.HotTrack` for the `LinkColor` property)
- It uses the old, ugly, aliased version of the hand cursor

I have found the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13439835/5144344) which claims to fix the cursor issue:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace System.Windows.Forms {
    public class LinkLabelEx : LinkLabel {
        private const int IDC_HAND = 32649;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);

        private static readonly Cursor SystemHandCursor = new Cursor(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, IDC_HAND));

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            // If the base class decided to show the ugly hand cursor
            if(OverrideCursor == Cursors.Hand) {
                // Show the system hand cursor instead
                OverrideCursor = SystemHandCursor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this solution is not perfect. For example, the old, ugly cursor flashes for one frame before the correct cursor is displayed when hovered over it.

I have also read about the native `SysLink` control in *ComCtl32.dll* which doesn't have there problems, but I can't find a good solution to use it in C#/WinForms. However I would prefer a pure .NET solution anyway.

How can I make the `LinkLabel` control better by solving above mentioned problems?

Comment: What's the question about? Creating `SysLink` control or fixing the cursor issue?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I only mentioned `SysLink` because it doesn't have the mentioned problems. However, if there is a pure .NET solution I would prefer that.

Comment: If you add the code to your question and be clear about *mentioned problems* which you are trying to solve, IMO it can be considered a good question and may reopen.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I rephrased my question now to be more clear about what I mean.

Comment: I voted to reopen.

Comment: Anyway I posted the answer to cursor problem in the linked post.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei  Reopened. I think you should post an answer here because  question and contexts are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the color, the control has come properties which allows you to change the link color: `LinkColor`, `ActiveLinkColor`, `VisitedLinkColor` and `DisabledLinkColor`.

The default values for those properties are coming from Internet Explorer settings which are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Settings` registry key.

To use different colors, you can set those properties based on your preference. For example you can set `LinkColor` to `SystemColors.HotTrack` or follow the recommendations by [w3org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints) for the colors and use `#0000EE` as default link color and `#551A8B` for visited link and `#FF0000` for active links.

About the blinking, it's because the code which you shared is setting the cursor on mouse move after the base class has changed the cursor. As a result, there is a chance for blinking the base class cursor before setting the new cursor. To solve the problem, you need to handle `WM_SETCURSOR` and set the cursor to system hand cursor when it's necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyLinkLabel : LinkLabel
{
    public MyLinkLabel()
    {
        this.LinkColor = Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x66, 0xCC);
        this.VisitedLinkColor = Color.FromArgb(0x80, 0x00, 0x80);
        this.ActiveLinkColor = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    }
    const int IDC_HAND = 32649;
    const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020;
    const int HTCLIENT = 1;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetCursor(HandleRef hcursor);

    static readonly Cursor SystemHandCursor = 
        new Cursor(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, IDC_HAND));
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR)
            WmSetCursor(ref msg);
        else
            base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
    void WmSetCursor(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.WParam == (IsHandleCreated ? Handle : IntPtr.Zero) &&
           (unchecked((int)(long)m.LParam) & 0xffff) == HTCLIENT)
        {
            if (OverrideCursor != null)
            {
                if (OverrideCursor == Cursors.Hand)
                    SetCursor(new HandleRef(SystemHandCursor, SystemHandCursor.Handle));
                else
                    SetCursor(new HandleRef(OverrideCursor, OverrideCursor.Handle));
            }
            else
            {
                SetCursor(new HandleRef(Cursor, Cursor.Handle));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DefWndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, even with `AutoSize = false` and `LinkArea`!